# spring-boot Persistent h2database in filesystem

Tags: spring-boot, h2

How can I configure spring-boot with h2database so as it reuses database each time I restart.

This is the only line I have in my application.properties file

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: what you mean "reuses database" ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to specify for `spring.datasource.url` a value that specifies a filesystem DB. You can do it by using the `jdbc:h2:file:` prefix.
For example, you could use this configuration to store the DB in a `mydb.mv.db` file in the `db` folder of your `home` directory:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:~/db/mydb
```

Note that `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` is not required. The url and the H2 JDBC driver located in the classpath at runtime are enough.

Note also that by default, the database will be automatically created at startup if you use an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby).

It is the case even if you specify a file as database in the JDBC URL.

So to avoid recreating the db at each Spring Boot startup, you should also add :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
```

Comment: Also need `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`  not `create-drop`

Comment: Any option to re-create in case of running tests ?

Comment: you should have a specific `application.properties`, for example `application-test.properties` to differentiate the two cases.